# How Async and Await works

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to understand how Async and Await works. How control travel in the program. Here is the code which I was trying to understand.

```
public async Task MyMethod()
{
    Task<int> longRunningTask = LongRunningOperation();
    //indeed you can do independent to the int result work here 
    MySynchronousMethod();
    //and now we call await on the task 
    int result = await longRunningTask;
    //use the result 
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

public async Task<int> LongRunningOperation() // assume we return an int from this long running operation 
{
    await Task.Delay(5000); //5 seconds delay
    return 1;
}

private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     MyMethod();
}
```

When button click occur then `MyMethod()` will be called and from the MyMethod `LongRunningOperation()` will be called and it take 5 sec to complete. so my question is

- What is the meaning of this line

  Task longRunningTask = LongRunningOperation();
- what this does `int result = await longRunningTask;`

The above line could be committed and one line we can construct like

```
Task<int> longRunningTask = await LongRunningOperation();
```

or

```
int result = await longRunningTask;
```

### Please can someone explain to me the above code which is not clear to me.

1) if the longRunningOperation hasn't finished and is still running, MyMethod() will return to its calling method, thus the main thread doesn't get blocked. When the longRunningOperation is done then a thread from the ThreadPool (can be any thread) will return to MyMethod() at its previous state and continue execution (in this case printing the result to the console).

A second case would be that the longRunningOperation has already finished its execution and the result is available. When reaching the await longRunningOperation the compiler knows that it has the result and will keep on executing code on the very same thread. (in this case printing result to console).

point 1 is not at all clear to me like the statement "`if the longRunningOperation hasn't finished and is still running, MyMethod() will return to its calling method`"

if possible explain the point one in more detail. thanks

Comment: Think about `yield return` which gives control to the calling code within the loop.

Comment: If you understand how `Task.ContinueWith(lambda)` works, you can think of code after `await` as of something you'd put inside the `lambda`. This metaphor doesn't take Synchronization Context into account.

Comment: Use this link. It provide a detail and depth information. http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async%E2%80%8E

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog that you may find helpful.

This code:

```
int result = await LongRunningOperation();
```

is essentially the same as this code:

```
Task<int> resultTask = LongRunningOperation();
int result = await resultTask;
```

So, yes, `LongRunningOperation` is invoked directly by that method.

When the `await` operator is passed an already-completed task, it will extract the result and continue executing the method (synchronously).

When the `await` operator is passed an incomplete task (e.g., the task returned by `LongRunningOperation` will not be complete), then by default `await` will capture the current context and return an incomplete task from the method.

Later, when the `await` task completes, the remainder of the method is scheduled to run in that context.

This "context" is `SynchronizationContext.Current` unless it is `null`, in which case it is `TaskScheduler.Current`. If you're running this in a Console app, then the context is usually the thread pool context, so the `async` method will resume executing on a thread pool thread. However, if you execute the same method on a UI thread, then the context is a UI context and the `async` method will resume executing on the UI thread.

Comment: Async and Await work on background thread or foreground thread ??

Comment: Neither; `async` is thread-agnostic. When you call an `async` method, it is invoked directly on the current thread. When an `async` method resumes after awaiting a task, it uses the "context" that I described in my answer to determine which thread to continue executing on.

Comment: That confused me completely... Let's say that MySyncMethod() takes 5 seconds and the LongRunnigOp() takes 3 seconds. If we have
`Task<int> resultTask = LongRunningOperation();
MySynchronousMethod();
int result = await resultTask;`
then it should take 5 seconds in total, while if we have
`int result = await LongRunningOperation();
MySynchronousMethod();` then it will take 8 seconds in total... Isnt' that right?

Comment: @StephenCleary, then, let's say in an ASP.NET app, what's the usefulness of having async methods that are called and awaited on the same line compared with their version of synchronous methods? For example why this method: `public async Task<Car> GetCarByIdAsync(int id) { return await carRepository.GetByIdAsync(id); }` is better than this one:  `public Car GetCarById(int id) { return carRepository.GetById(id); }` ? Is the only advantage that the async method will free the thread that can be used by another process in the OS, while the call to the DB is made? Am I getting it right?

Comment: @John: Yes, the thread is freed up to do other work (in the same process).

Comment: @StephenCleary - One thing I don't understand is how does it execute LongRunningOperation () ? i.e. which thread will execute the content of LongRunningOperation ()

Comment: @HiteshP: `LongRunningOperation` *starts* on whatever thread calls it. But [there is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) that is just sitting there for 5 seconds waiting for the timer to go off.

Answer (score 40):

I've been taught about it in the following fashion, I found it to be quite a clear and concise explanation:

```
//this is pseudocode
async Method()
{
    code;
    code;
    await something; 
    moreCode;
}
```

When `Method` is invoked, it executes its contents (`code;` lines) up to `await something;`. At that point, `something;` is fired and the method ends like a `return;` was there.

`something;` does what it needs to and then returns.

When `something;` returns, execution gets back to `Method` and proceeds from the `await` onward, executing `moreCode;`

In a even more schematic fashion, here's what happens:

1. Method is invoked
2. `code;` is executed
3. `something;` is executed, flow goes back to the point where `Method` was invoked
4. execution goes on with what comes after the `Method` invocation
5. when `something;` returns, flow returns inside `Method`
6. `moreCode;` is executed and `Method` itself ends (yes, there could be something else `await`-ing on it too, and so on and so forth)

Comment: I've been missing number 3 the whole time. This is the only answer that actually explains what really happens in a comprehensible fashion.

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful

Comment: This is that answer I was searching for.. Simple, clear and comprehensive.

Comment: Very clear explaination, just a clarification if someone can. I am not sure I understand what does step #4 means? So for ex: if uber method (which is calling method();) would be like ... CodeA; var x = await Method(); CodeB; . Based on set #4 while something; is still processing (probably on another thread), control will come back to original method and CodeB will be executed? yes? I though that's the whole point that whenever there is await code execution will stop there. Hence task shall go back to pool and service any other caller. Thanks

Comment: I think this is one of the best explanations of async operations I've read. Making it language-agnostic is genius. What would make it slightly more useful is putting `Method` in the context of a broader program, and showing that the code after method is invoked continues (I know you say that in your point 3, but some example pseudo-code would make it even clearer). In particular, this make is clear why calls to an async method can't be relied on to return an actual object (because the following code might run before the async op finishes), and instead usually return something like a promise.

Comment: @rockvista no. In your example CodeB won´t be executed until Method did not finished, because you asked the compiler to await Method. BUT, if you call: 
"CodeA; Method(); CodeB; " then CodeB will be executed while Method is executing.

Answer (score 12):

Behind the scenes C# compiler actually converts your code into a state machine. It generates a lot more code so that behind the scenes every time a await task or async action is completed, it'll continue execution from where it left off. In terms of your question, every time the async action has finished, the async method will be called back on the calling thread when you originally started the call to the async method. Eg it'll execute your code on the thread that you started on. So the async action will be run on a `Task` thread, then the result will be returned back on the thread you method was originally called on and keep executing.

`Await` will get the value from the `Task` or async action and "unbox" it from the task when the execution is returned. In this case it will automatically put it into the int value, so no need to store the `Task<int>`.

Your code has the problem where it await's on the `LongRunningTask()` you'd most likely just want to return the long task method without the `async`, then have your `MyMethod` perform the await.

```
int value = await LongWaitingTask()
```

[Async Await and the Generated StateMachine](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/535635/Async-Await-and-the-Generated-StateMachine)

It's a requirement of `async` methods that you return a `Task` or `void`.

It's possible to change it so when you return back from executing the async task it will execute the remaining code on the thread the async task was performed on using the [`Task.ConfigureAwait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait) method.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to think about it this way:
Whenever you have an `await`, the compiler splits your method into 2: one part before the `await` and another part after it.
The second part runs after the first one has finished successfully.

In your code, the first method will look like something roughly equivalent to this:

```
public async Task MyMethod()
{
    Task<int> longRunningTask = LongRunningOperation();
    MySynchronousMethod();

    longRunningTask.ContinueWith(t => part2(t.Result));
}

void part2(int result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Few important notes:

1. It's obviously much more complex than this since it should support
   try-catch and others. Also, it doesn't really use the task
2. `Task` is not actually being used directly. It's using the task's `GetAwaiter()` method and its API, or any other class with this method or extension method.
3. If there are multiple awaits in a method it's being split multiple times.
4. If `MyMethod` is being split, how does someone who awaits `MyMethod` knows when all parts are done? When your async method returns a `Task`, the compiler generates a special `Task` which tracks everything with a state machine.