# Why does this async method not have a compile error?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

Maybe this is due to my lack of understanding of what happens during compilation when a method is marked `async`, but why does this method compile?

```
    public async Task<bool> Test()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Just looking for an explanation here, so I can better understand what is going on. Is a `Task` automatically getting wrapped? Why is this method allowed? (it does not adhere to the method signature, which is to return a `Task<bool>`).

**Update**:
It appears that this is also applicable for parameters to:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        Input(Test);
    }

    public async Task<bool> Test()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Input(Func<Task<bool>> test)
    {

    }
```

where, the Test method returns a `Task` implicitly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Async and Await works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349210/how-async-and-await-works)

Comment: You aren't required to `await` something in an `async` method. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @RufusL right I understand that. but i do not understand why method 1 does not have to return a Task<bool> (which, based on its signature it should)

Comment: [Async return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types) return the result of a task, not the task itself. In your example, the `async Task<bool>` returns a `bool`.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Suppose you had `async Task<bool> FooAsync() { await Whatever(); return true; }` would you also ask why that method was compiling?  I think you might not understand that a `Task<T>` `return`s a `T` in an async method; `return t;` means *complete the task with this T* in an async method, just as `return t;` means *complete this method with a T* in non-async code.

Comment: @EricLippert actually, you are correct. I would not have questioned it if the method body itself was awaiting on something. thanks for providing a better understanding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at the decompiled version of your code [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLACgoGYECY4DCcA3hnOQjlABwKICsAdFAGwA8ARgPZcA2AfHACyACgCUJMhWlQA7HABmAQ14BnAKZp00gL4YdQA==)

```
using System;
public class C {
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> M() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The method is compiled into a normal async one, with the state machine, it does return a `Task<bool>` after all.

```
public class C
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <M>d__0 : IAsyncStateMachine
    {
        public int <>1__state;

        public AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<bool> <>t__builder;

        public C <>4__this;

        //called when you awaiting the Task
        void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
        {
            int num = this.<>1__state;
            bool result;
            try
            {
                result = false;  //the result is set
            }
            catch (Exception arg_0C_0)
            {
                Exception exception = arg_0C_0;
                this.<>1__state = -2;
                this.<>t__builder.SetException(exception);
                return;
            }
            this.<>1__state = -2;
            this.<>t__builder.SetResult(result); 
        }

        [DebuggerHidden]
        void IAsyncStateMachine.SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
        {
        }
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough, AsyncStateMachine(typeof(C.<M>d__0))]
    public Task<bool> M()
    {
        // the state machine instance created
        C.<M>d__0 <M>d__ = new C.<M>d__0(); 
        <M>d__.<>4__this = this;
        <M>d__.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<bool>.Create();
        <M>d__.<>1__state = -1;
        AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<bool> <>t__builder = <M>d__.<>t__builder;
        <>t__builder.Start<C.<M>d__0>(ref <M>d__);
        return <M>d__.<>t__builder.Task;
    }
}
```

BTW, the compiler gives you a warning, because you never `await` in your method:

> warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run
>   synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await
>   non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work
>   on a background thread.

And you're absolutely right, you may just return a completed task instead:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public class C {
    public Task<bool> M() {
        return Task.FromResult(false); //no need to await here at all
    }
```

}

The other ways to code the method above [could be found here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLAChYMQVjZgZgQCY4BhOAbwzloSKgA4EA2AHgCMB7LgGwD44AWQAUASio060qAHY4AMwCGvAM4BTfNIC+U2nvoJmUdtz6ChxcdXTSZ8qAE5WAOgBiAJy4BbAErrVAFdeABcRZTV1MS06XVs6AygGUx4BYQJrA3tXTx9/INDwlQ1ogzjtIA===).

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public class C {
    public async Task<bool> M() {
        return false;
    }

    public async Task<bool> M2(){
        return await Task.FromResult(false);
    }

    public Task<bool> M3(){
        return Task.FromResult(false);
    }
}
```

I hope this will clarify things for you.

Comment: Not sure that I understand you. It does return a task. See the decompiled code. Even if you do `return false;` the actual state machine is built and the task returned. The caller may `await` on it, or just store/pass the task further.

Comment: so, it implicitly returns a Task simply by adding the async keyword? Would compiled code be any different if I was to return Task.Run(()=>true) and remove the async keyword?

Comment: Please check the last link in my answer. When you `await` the whole state machine staff is built and initialized. Will all the performance/memory penalty :) If you just return a completed task (`Task.FromResult`) none of that is taking place.

Comment: You can also play with the `Task.Run` there. You'll see that it's not really different, it's just another factory method for the `Task<>` object.

Comment: And yes, the compiler changes the code so that it returns a `Task` when you add the `async` keyword. That's pretty much a syntax sugar for an old concept. Just less code to write.

Comment: Long time ago we used to write a very chatty code for that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming